# "Неинтересен тебе" или "неинтересен для тебя"?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, падежи

"Я стал тебе неинтересен" или "Я стал неинтересен для тебя"?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется так:

**Я стал неинтересен тебе**. Так можно сказать  об изменении  личного отношения  к человеку при продолжительном знакомстве.

**Я стал неинтересен для тебя.** В этом случае скорее говорится об отношениях, которые только складывались, но так и не сложились.

Как это объяснить

Дательный беспредложный падеж обозначает прямую направленность на предмет, в то время как родительный падеж обозначает действие в пределах границ предмета. Другими словами, если предмет **интересен мне**, то речь обычно идёт о конкретном предмете. Если же предмет **интересен для меня**, то он входит в круг моих интересов (это может быть даже ещё незнакомый мне предмет).

Примеры:

1) Когда интересный тебе журнал держишь в руках ― это другое качество восприятия. Удивительное это счастье ― жить с тем, кому ты интересна и кто интересен тебе.

2) У меня вечером будет человек, очень интересный для тебя, между прочим. Надеюсь мой блог будет полезен и интересен для тебя.

Answer (score 0):

В Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правки, Розенталь, Д. Э. говорится следующее:

**При выборе вариантных беспредложных и предложных конструкций типа вытянуться линией** – **вытянуться в линию, собираться группами – собираться в группы** *учитывается различие в смысловых оттенках: предложные сочетания в линию, в группы указывают на большую степень концентрации действия.*

Обычно предложные конструкции, в которых отношения между словами выражаются не только падежным окончанием, но и предлогом, имеют более конкретный характер, связь между словами уточняется.

Так, сопоставляя сочетания лицо у девушки – лицо девушки, отмечаем в первом из них более четкое выражение принадлежности и связь со сказуемым в контексте предложения (ср.: лицо у девушки побледнело).

Такое же различие в смысловых оттенках (более конкретное значение предложных конструкций) находим в приводимых ниже парах: **интересный всем – интересный для всех,** нужный многим – нужный для многих, полезный детям – полезный для детей, понятный каждому – понятный для каждого, приятный друзьям – приятный для друзей, чуждые нам взгляды – чуждые для нас взгляды **(во всех этих сочетаниях предлог для подчеркивает связь с лицом – косвенным объектом).** Ср. также: видеть первый раз – видеть в первый раз, охотиться летней порой – охотиться в летнюю пору, перпендикулярный плоскости – перпендикулярный к плоскости, приверженность науке – приверженность к науке и т.п.